# Hockeykit Invaild Provisionary Profile?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, ota, hockeyapp

We have recently setup a HockeyKit server for testing purposes of our iOS app. We have followed the [HockeyKit Docs](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeyKit/wiki) and the [Apple Doc's for OTA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505). We followed everything and set everything up, but we are having an issue with installing the provisioning profile.

We can click on the "Install Profile", but nothing happens.
We can click on the "Install App", and the app will install but fail due to "Invalid Profile".

We have tried several different profiles, and all fail....

Here is a console output from the device

```
profiled[328] : (Error) MC: Failed to parse profile data. Error: NSError:
Desc : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code : 1000
Type : MCFatalError
Dec 1 14:32:31 iPad1 profiled[328] : (Error) MC: Profile cannot be queued for installation. Error: NSError:
Desc : Invalid Profile
Sugg : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
US Sugg: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
Code : 4000
Type : MCFatalError
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc : Invalid Profile
US Desc: Invalid Profile
Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
Code : 1000
Type : MCFatalError
```

We have have filed an [issue](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeyKit/issues/185) on their GitHub as well.

What are we missing from this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing provisioning profile manually stopped working with iOS 8 (feature removed by Apple). You need to always create a new build in Xcode with the updated profile and upload this new build to your HockeyKit server.

Comment: I no longer use HockeyApp, after this and finding a memory leak in the SDK I had switched to Fabric. But from my understanding, this however _seems_ to be the correct answer.